# How to Create an Editable Pivot View in Odoo v15

Tags: pivot, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14, odoo-15

Is there a way to make a pivot table (that is NOT aggreagated) editable directly from the pivot view in Odoo (I'm using Odoo v15)?
For example let's say I have my model as the following:

| product_id | date | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 01/11/2021 | 10 |
| p1 | 01/12/2021 | 20 |
| p2 | 01/11/2021 | 30 |

and I want to use a pivot view to show the table by **date** columns and **qty** as values (NO aggregation will be used, meaning NO sum/avg/count funtions are needed) while making the pivot table editable so the user can edit the values directly, see bellow example for reference:

| product_id | 01/11/2021 | 01/12/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 10 | 20 |
| p2 | 30 | 0 |

Please let me know if you have any ideas how to do so. Thanks!

Comment: Right now it is out of the box, you should create your own pivot view for achieve that writing your custom module with all js involve.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes that's what I found out, for Odoo Enterprise users they can use *grid view*